# Fetch API not showing json data

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am relatively new to react native and trying to build an app and am using the `fetch` API to try and get a json file from the api. My problem is that it seems to not have any response when i make the calls to the api.

Here is the function that contains the fetch calls

```
export const fetchData = url => {
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchingRequest());
        try {
          let response = await fetch(url);
          let json = response.json();
          console.log(json);
          dispatch(fetchingSuccess(json));
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch(fetchingFailure(error));
        }
      };
    };
```

The `console.log(json)` does not come up when I check in the chrome debugger.

if the url is needed for reference, I used `https://randomuser.me/api/`.

This function is called in one of my other components. I am also using `redux` and `redux-thunk` to store the data in the JSON file.

Edited in:

I believe the problem to be the function is not being executed when called.

I import the function and all the `redux` actions like this

```
import {
  fetchingSuccess,
  fetchingRequest,
  fetchingFailure,
  fetchData
} from "../data/redux/actions/appActions.js";
```

The `fetchData` function is then called in a `_onPress` function that is written like this

```
_onPress = () => {
    let url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10"
    fetchData(url);
    console.log("should have fetched");
};
```

in the console the expected output should be the

```
JSON contents or error // logged when fetchData is called
should have fetched // logged from _onPress
```

but instead the console outputs

```
should have fetched // logged from _onPress
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that response.json() returns a promise, so when you do:

```
let json = response.json();
```

Without the await then the log after is still a promise, in order for this to work you must add the await in front of the response.json():

```
let json = await response.json();
```

> The **json()** method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads
>   it to completion. It **returns a promise** that resolves with the result
>   of parsing the body text as JSON.

Comment: I added the `await` command and it still seems to not display the JSON file in the console.

Comment: @dpatel125 then the problem is that the execution never reaches that point. Try to find where it goes, maybe it throws an error?

Comment: @dpatel125 if you are using await, it can be that the fetch is never resolved, and in that case, even if the code is inside the try{} it will never reach the console.log. Check if the fetch is resolved.

Comment: i think the problem may lie in the function being called. I have edited the post to show what I mean

Comment: Thanks! I was having this exact same problem with a Google Calendar React Native fetch call.